# 3D JS Engine for 2D development?

Tags: javascript, 3d, 2d, three.js

I'm about to jump into some simple game development with Javascript.  I would like to one day transition to 3D development but for now am only going to be doing 2D "top down" objects.
I know that this isn't ideal but I feel like it will help me get familiar with the 3D "environment".

I am using [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) as it appears to be very well developed and I like that it can do Canvas, WebGL and SVG.  However, my very first problem I've come across is, I don't know how to "move" an object.  Using just Canvas I can easily take an object I have rendered and modify it's .x or .y property to "move" it.  However, for Three.js objects so far all I've found is `object.rotation.x`, etc.  I can move the camera, but this doesn't work because I need objects to move individually.

So I guess what I'm looking for is any resources into Three.js for 2D development, or developing a 2D top-down game in a 3D environment.

Comment: Alright, I did just figure out the moving individual objects, it needs to be applied to the Mesh, not the "Geometry"...but I would still like resources on this subject if possible.

Comment: I'm also interested in 2D programming using Three.js and WebGL. The links below are all 3D-specific. Were you able to find any 2D resources?

Comment: None.  I moved away from trying to do 2D work in a 3D environment.  Too much effort and too little documentation.

Answer (score 6):

1. The [Getting Started](http://www.aerotwist.com/lab/getting-started-with-three-js/) article is pretty good.
2. [LearningThree.js](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/categories/tutorial3dgame/) got a series on "let's make a 3D Game".
3. There is a nice [searchable reference](http://threejs.org/io/s/) available too.

Note that the project moves super fast so the API might change
here and there, so keep an eye out on [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) and when you
update always read the change log to see if you need to update your code.

Gooduck!.